# Dog training commands in Klingon

Tags: star-trek, klingon-language

I am training my pitbull to be my service dog and I want to train him his commands in Klingon. At this point I need words for "sit", "stay", "heel", and a sound comparable to Cesar Milan's "ssttt".

Are there any suitable Klingon words I can use?

Comment: @closevoters I don't at all understand how Klingon is off-topic?

Comment: Possibly someone at the Trek BBS could help - https://www.trekbbs.com/ -   or https://www.kli.org/     or http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/MainPage     or  https://github.com/PanderMusubi/klingon

Comment: There is also [conlang.se] where questions on Klingon are on-topic

Comment: I'm a bit lazy to write a proper answer, so here's a Reddit post I wrote on the topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/3kuu3j/got_a_dog_for_protection_for_my_mom_and_named_her/cv0q0qs/

Answer (score 5):

According to Mark Okrand's [The Klingon Dictionary](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Klingon-Dictionary-English-Star-Trek/dp/067174559X) we have

- *ba'* (sit)
- *mev* (cease/stop)
- *chol* (get close/come here)

I can't help you with [tsch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aS3zyd5HfUQ)

Comment: I was really hoping that link would lead to the South Park episode...